# Remove elements identified by class, which meet id condition

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all elements identified by `.custom_class`, where `data-id` is less than `id-15`.

When I say "less", I mean integer part.

sample code:

```
<div class="custom_class" data-id="id-15">
<div class="different_class" data-id="id-14">
<div class="other_class" data-id="id-13">
<div class="custom_class" data-id="id-12">
<div class="other_class" data-id="id-11">
<div class="custom_class" data-id="id-10">
```

Comment: So, what have you tried in order to do this?

Comment: And what problem do you have exactly? Where are you stuck? Did you have a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/?

Comment: `$('.custom_class').filter(function () {...}).remove()` would be a start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this:

```
$('.custom_class').filter(function() {
    return +$(this).data('id').split('-')[1] < 15;
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/G8sMt/

Comment: Is the plus sing a typo? "+$(this..."

Comment: @celerno No, + sign is very important. Without it expression `typeof $(this).data('id').split('-')[1] => "string"`, while we need a number to compare with `15`. Type casting. You can use `parseInt` or `Number` too.

Comment: Actually, if you use `<` and one operand is not a string (`15`), the other operand is converted to a number as well (http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5). But explicit type casting makes things clearer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".custom_class").each(function() {
    if(isIdLessThan15($(this).id)){
     //do your stuff
    }
});

function isIdLessThan15(idValue){
   var intPart= idValue.Split('-')[1];
   if(intPart<15)
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.custom_class').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).data('id') < 'id15';
}).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jVHxT/